# What would be the best way to autonomously/conditionally load more data without manually triggering an event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a paginated list where the data comes from an api. The data is limited to 24 objects per page. It should also be noted that there's infinite scrolling. For smaller screens infinite scroll is fine but with larger screens the next call to the api won't be called due to the fact that the page has no scroll (not enough content fills up the page).

I currently have a load more button at the bottom of the list if the window has no scroll:

```
const { data, meta: { prev_page, next_page } } = this.props.albums;

const displayLoadMoreButton = document.body.scrollHeight < window.innerHeight && !!next_page;

<InfiniteScroll
  dataLength={ data.length }
  next={ this.fetchAdditional }
  hasMore={ !!next_page }
>
  <div className="album-grid">
    { this.renderAlbums() }
  </div>

  {displayLoadMoreButton ? (
    <LoadMoreButton loadMoreFunc={ this.fetchAdditional } />
  ) : (
    null
  )}
</InfiniteScroll>
```

I was wondering if it were at all possible to pre-determine whether to load more objects and when there is scroll on the page display the album-grid in this case? Writing a conditional and calling the fetchAdditional method in any of the life-cycles will only result in an infinite loop error (for obvious reasons).

Comment: You'd have to get a ref for the actual DOM element containing the rows, then compare its height with the height of the screen.

Comment: The problem with that is that I run into a loop. Let's say on my first render to the DOM it displays (x) amount of albums. The screen check would occur in one life cycle which will trigger the error. Unless I'm approaching this wrong.

Comment: You could avoid the infinite loop by just loading one extra page each time the lifecycle is called, until the screen is full (or if your rows are the same height, you could load the specific number of pages needed to fill the screen). Alternatively, unless you're trying to learn about writing a list with infinite scroll yourself, you could use an existing package like [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) to make things easier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was looking over one of the related packages on that page, react-virtualized-auto-sizer. Does this essentially do what I want to accomplish? In regards to filling the page with albums until complete?

Comment: I've never used it, but it looks promising.

Comment: All good. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.